# Can not initialize realm - Invaid object name UM_DOMAIN

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to upgrade to WSO2 identity server 4.6.0 from version 4.0.0 .I have changed "user-mgmt.xml" as mentioned in the documentation. So far I have not changed existing backend model.

When I start WSO2 Identity server I get following errors:

```
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Invalid object 'UM_DOMAIN'
...
...
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Invalid column name 'UM_MAPPED_ATTRIBUTE_DOMAIN'
```

I checked the backend and mentioned table/column is missing. However things worked fine with WSO2 4.0.0, so Are these domain changes part of 4.6.0 version or something is wrong with "user-mgmt.xml"?

Following is user-mgmt xml

```
<UserManager>
<Realm>
    <Configuration>
    <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                 <UserName>admin</UserName>
                 <Password>admin</Password>
            </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> 
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
    </Configuration>
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="IsEmailUserName">false</Property>
        <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
        <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
        <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupEnabled">false</Property>
        <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
    </UserStoreManager>
<AuthorizationManager
        class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
        <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
    <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    </AuthorizationManager>
</Realm>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are major schema changes between those two IS versions (between IS 4.0.0 and IS 4.6.0). Therefore you need to update the back end model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate the database too.. Refer the [migration guide](https://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Database+Migration+Guide) for the steps of migrations.

HTH,

DarRay